# $scope error in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, scope

I'm trying to use AngularJS to build my application, and I'm faced to a problem with the $scope context.

This is my app main file :

```
var app = angular.module('app', 
[ 
    'matchCtrl', 
    'matchService',
    'ngRoute'
]);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', { templateUrl: '../app/views/partials/home.html' })
        // all routes for matches
        .when('/matches', { templateUrl: '../app/views/partials/matches.html', controller: "matchController" })
        .when('/matches/:id', { templateUrl: '../app/views/partials/match_place.html', controller: "matchController" })

        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});
```

I've got one controller that's call matchController. It look like this and have just to catch the data with the get and show method of my match factory.

Here, the controller :

```
angular.module('matchCtrl', [])

    .controller('matchController', function($scope, $http, Match) {

        // object to hold all the data for the new match form
        $scope.matchData = {};

        // loading variable to show the spinning loading icon
        $scope.loading = true;

        // get all the matches first and bind it to the $scope.matches object
        Match.get()
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.matches = data;
                $scope.loading = false;
            });

        $scope.showPlaces = function(id) {

            $scope.loading = true;

            console.log($scope);

            Match.show(id)
                .success(function(data){
                    $scope.places = data;
                    console.log($scope.places);
                    $scope.loading = false;
                });
        };
    });
```

Here, the factory. I'm using Laravel as an API Backend to catch data, and all routes "api/***" are defined in my Laravale routes file.

```
angular.module('matchService', [])

    .factory('Match', function($http) {

        return {
            get : function() {
                return $http.get('api/matches');
            },
            show : function(id) {
                return $http.get('api/matches/' + id);
            },
        }

    });
```

Here my index file, and my partial where I want to use the $scope.place variable.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Laravel and Angular test</title>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body class="container">
        <div ng-view></div>

        <script src="js/controllers/matchCtrl.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/placeCtrl.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services/matchService.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services/placeService.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The partial view :

```
<div class="place text-center">
    <ul>
        <li>{{ place.name }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My problem is that on the partial view, the $scope is not the same that in my main view. And then, I can't access to my $scope.place variable and use it into the view.

Comment: I dont see any ng-controller directive in your main view that is creating any scope...

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm just stupid. I just give the ng-controller="matchController" attribute in my main view and it's work. And then, I can put others controllers in my route for any partial view ?

Comment: exactly then you can add controllers to take over scope when u change routes... not to be advertising ui-router when you arent looking for it, but i really recommend this solution to the routing paradigm in angular...

Answer (score 1):

Add a controller to you index to get access to its scope

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Laravel and Angular test</title>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body class="container" ng-controller="MatchController">
        <div ng-view></div>

        <script src="js/controllers/matchCtrl.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/placeCtrl.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services/matchService.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services/placeService.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add ng-controller at

```
<div class="place text-center" ng-controller="MatchController">
    <ul>
        <li>{{ place.name }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this context the module can not reference the controllers because it was last declared in its index.html

Please change the order to the next and try again.

```
<body class="container" ng-controller="MatchController">
        <div ng-view></div>
        <!--Note the file app.js come before others-->
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/matchCtrl.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/placeCtrl.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services/matchService.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services/placeService.js"></script>
    </body>
```